# SVG: include image with color attribute

Tags: image, svg, colors

I'm trying to load an SVG image into an other SVG image. This works pretty well. However, I can't seem to change the color of the loaded/embedded image from the main file.

In the w3 specs (https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElement) it says I could use the `presentation attribute` `color`.

Here is what I have, the main svg is generated by PHP (so I can easily use dynamic colors & dynamic included images):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="75" height="105" viewBox="0 0 229 323" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
<defs></defs>
    <g id="Welcome" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
    <g id="markers_version_1" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" transform="translate(-290.000000, -669.000000)" fill="#ff9900">
        <g id="video_marker" transform="translate(290.000000, 669.000000)" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup">
            <path d="M112.666748,321.132938 C113.679225,322.44023 115.323763,322.440513 116.333252,321.132938 C116.333252,321.132938 229,177.318681 229,114.230769 C229,51.1428574 177.736604,0 114.5,0 C51.2633961,0 0,51.1428574 0,114.230769 C0,177.318681 112.666748,321.132938 112.666748,321.132938 Z" id="Oval-video"></path>
        </g>
    </g>
    <image xlink:href="test.svg" x="50" y="40" height="120px" width="120px" color="#ff9900" />
</g>
</svg>
```

(test.svg, simple svg for testing :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 229 323" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;">
    <path d="M205,110.25C205,89.691 188.309,73 167.75,73L80.25,73C59.691,73 43,89.691 43,110.25L43,184.75C43,205.309 59.691,222 80.25,222L167.75,222C188.309,222 205,205.309 205,184.75L205,110.25Z" />
</svg>
```

I've searched on SO and the rest of the internet, and see some other ways to add color to the image element, like `style="fill:#ff9900"` or `style="color:#ff9900"` but they don't seem to work.

Hoping someone can point me into the right direction.

Comment: I see no reference to the presentation attribute color in the referenced link.

Comment: That could be my issue, how should I reference it?

Comment: You can't, images are self-contained and are not externally modifable.

Comment: So, the w3 documentation is wrong? Or am I missing what presentation attributes are?

Comment: I believe the documentation is correct, although I don't know what exactly you're reading to draw the incorrect inferences you are doing though.

Comment: That I should be able to set a color attribute on the image element, defining the color of the included image. Perhaps I'm reading it wrong. Thanks for your help